# Why didn't Sheldon provide his references for sports statistics to his dad and meemaw?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-big-bang-theory, young-sheldon

Why didn't Sheldon provide his references for sports statistics to his dad and meemaw so they could (try to) learn it on their own?

Wherever Sheldon read about punting on fourth or whatever could be read by his dad (I guess) sooooo.........

Perhaps they couldn't learn the maths but at least they can know (perhaps not understand or interpret) the results.

I imagine a related question for Bernadette's dad, but I don't quite remember the episode at the moment.

A - it's a sitcom. There would be no plot otherwise

B - bclc overlooked something.

C - other

Comment: Everyone can read books but everyone can't be intelligent enough to understand it fully

Comment: @AnkitSharma um third paragraph?

Comment: I suppose Sheldon have to recalculate stuff of many situations, so it's not going to be that easy.

Comment: What episode of the show is this question referring to?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist the sports statistics episode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statistics is not a cup of tea for everyone. You have to gather numerical data, then classify and analysis them in order to interpret the possible outcome.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics),

> Statistics is a branch of mathematics dealing with the collection, classification, analysis, interpretation of numerical facts, for drawing inferences on the basis of their quantifiable likelihood (probability) of data.

For statistics, you must be good at Maths. Also, as @AnkitSharma mentioned, Sheldon has to gather data and process it in order to interpret the possible outcome for every game, which won't be an easy thing to do for Meemaw and Sheldon's father.

Comment: Dude I have an account on maths and stats se. I'm not a n00b. Thanks. Actually perhaps this is too specific for a sitcom especially one that's a spin off of TBBT but there were some cases where Sheldon was able to state some conclusions that seemed to be well known like punt on fourth or something. It's not like it was rare research or like Sheldon did his own research, at least that's my understanding. So at least for that conclusion, there must have been a reference. Even if the dad can't understand the reasoning the dad can at least trust the credibility of the source:

Comment: ...if the source is right about punt on fourth it's probably right about other stuff? As for degree of rightness...ummm...is 95% certain difficult to interpret? I forgot. Been 7 years since introduction to mathematical statistics (yes it was with calculus and linear algebra. Later we had hell of a lot more statistics in grad school. We even used real analysis).

Comment: In the beginning of that episode, when Sheldon first tells about the punt down and his dad tells that he's not right, he does the calculation in his mind. So, he didn't actually researched about it, but he took the data and gave statistics.

Comment: lol. Honestly wasn't expecting a good explanation. Good thing I gave Chuck Lorre the botd. Hehe. Good job, and thanks!